# "for" loop inside another "for" loop

Tags: php

I have quick question, and I'm sure some of you guys will be able to point out what I'm doing wrong.
Basically, I want to create a table with (calendar), with the months and days of an entire year, and Im using php to do it, my code is doing something weird.
What happens is that January is empty and the days for January are being put in february.
My code so far is as follows:

```
$months = 12;
$monthsOfTheyear = array("Januany","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
$currentMonth = date("n");
$currentYear = date("Y");
$daysOfTheMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $currentMonth, $currentYear);
for($i = 0; $i < $months; $i++){
echo    "   <tbody class='month'>";
echo    "       <tr>
                    <td colspan='".$daysOfTheMonth."'>
                        ".$monthsOfTheyear[$i]."
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
        ";
$daysOfEachMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, $currentYear);
    for($d = 1; $d <= $daysOfEachMonth; $d++){

        echo    "   <td>
                        ".$d."
                    </td>
                ";
    }
    echo    "       </tr>
            </tbody";
}
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I've been staring at the monitor for about an hour trying to figure it out.
I'd appreciate any advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
$daysOfEachMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, $currentYear);
```

You are using $i. The first value is 0. That's why you don't get any value.

if u use

```
$daysOfEachMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i+1, $currentYear);
```

you solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `0` as month number of January to function [`cal_days_in_month`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) which is incorrect. The function expects `1` for January.

So change `$i` to `$i+1`:

```
$daysOfEachMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i+1, $currentYear);
                                                      ^^
```

Looks like you've warnings disabled. If you enable them you'll see the following warning for your existing code:

```
PHP Warning:  cal_days_in_month(): invalid date.
```

Comment: Arrrg I've been 51 seconds late! I'm giving you +1.

Comment: Alternatively, the initial loop could be called as `for($i = 1; $i <= $months; $i++)`, but I see that that would screw up pulling down the name of the month.  Though, given that $i is only used before it's needed for `$daysofeachmonth`, it could be done like `for($i = 0; $i <= $months;)` and then do `$i++;` before `$daysofeachmonth` but after `$monthsoftheyear[$i]`.  Also, in the array of months you have "Januany" instead of "January".

Answer (score 2):

If this line:

```
$daysOfEachMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, $currentYear);
```

Becomes this line:

```
$daysOfEachMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i + 1, $currentYear);
```

Does it solve anything?